# What conduit should I install underground that meets code?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance, conduit

I want to run a conduit under my front yard about 20 feet. I will be trenching to 18 inches deep, but was curious what the easiest conduit is to install that meets code? PVC? EMT? Liquidtight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PVC is probably the easiest, and cheapest.  Just remember to glue your joints, and install expansion fittings where appropriate.

Comment: Where are expansion joints appropriate?

Comment: Answered my own question: http://www.carlonsales.com/techinfo/installationtraining/IT-NEMAEXJTA.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Rigid nonmetallic approved for direct burial  (at 18" PVC is the easiest and cheapest way to go)